# C# VSTO: visual studio loads the workbook but not the worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-dna

I'm currently using VSTO. Normally, when I load a new project, the first thing that appears is a worksheet that Visual Studio created automatically. But now, this page is totally blue, like this

[image]

When I try to debug the project as it stands, the workbook will be loaded, but the worksheet will not, like this

[image]

The last thing I did before having this problem was install Excel DNA in another project that I'm working on.

I've already tried to search for solution online but I haven't found anything.

I'm using:
Windows 10 / Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus / Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Did you try removing Excel-DNA (and perhaps repairing VSTO) to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: yes, i did. The problem remained.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an Excel 2016 bug that is triggered when you have an .xll add-in installed - presumably the Excel-DNA add-in in your case, but any C/C++ .xll add-in would also cause this behaviour.

There was a [discussion on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2bb21bfb-4940-4a68-9656-743ae0b8b4da/bug-in-excel-2016-excel-starts-with-no-default-workbook-or-start-page-if-an-xll-is-registered?forum=exceldev) which seems to indicate the  bug has been fixed in recent Excel 2016 updates.

Comment: It worked! I cannot upvote your answer because I'm new here, but it was definetly useful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

change excel option:
option-->General-->User interface options
when using multiple displays:
optimize for compatibility
will solve this problem.